# How to add a custom keyboard layout to Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, keyboard-layout

I'd like to add a custom keyboard layout in Linux Mint. The layout I'm trying to add can be found at [this website](http://arjenvankol.com/dvorak.php).

However, I can't seem to find where the layouts are stored and google-searching (and the instructions from the website) only leads me to folders and files that do not exist in Linux Mint, or at least my version of it (should be the standard one).

So, my question is basically, how do I add a custom keyboard layout in Linux Mint?
To clear things up: I want to add/install a NEW custom keyboard layout, not add/select one from the already installed ones.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zsmHNLIpw9Y

Comment: there are several dvorak variants available (see `man xkeyboard-config` for a list).  the US-based dvorak layouts are in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`, in clauses named `"dvorak", "dvorak-intl", "dvp"`, etc.  if none of those are satisfactory you can use one of them as a template to construct your own layout.

Answer (score 2):

The standard keyboard layouts are found under /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/